# Is it possible to create a field group that can be modified across entry types?

Tags: entry-type, fieldtypes, group

Sorry if this is asked/answered elsewhere. I tried to search for it with no success.

Suppose I have a common group of fields that I want to include in different entry types, and each entry will have unique data entered in the fields. A concrete example is:

**SEO / Meta**

- meta title
- meta description
- meta keywords

Later on I want to remove the "meta keywords" field from every entry type that has this "field group". Is there a way — *preferably with core Craft abilities* — to set it up so I can update the field group in one place and not have to touch every entry type?

A matrix field with max 1 would get the job done but feels plain wrong for this.

I have the feeling there is another way I just don't know about yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, field groups are just a way to have your fields grouped in the field layout designer and fields index page. Another advantage is the possibility to drag a whole group in the designer to create a new tab.

Approaches, other than a max 1 Matrix field you mentioned, that I can think of are:

- multiple predefined rows in a Table field
- multiple predefined rows in a [Set Table](https://github.com/engram-design/SetTable) field, which allows you to have a read only "Label" column and set a max rows
- custom solution implementing a [new field type](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/field-types) that has multiple input fields

Comment: Thanks @carlcs. Nice to know what the options are, and this might be a job for a plugin rather than the overhead of another matrix (from what I've read they should be used sparingly). I have to admit I tried to think of some similar use cases and didn't come up with much (maybe too brain-dead now, or in general). So I'll spare them the feature request :-)